# Herding lessons / sheepdog training classes in Japan?

Tags: japan, study, pets

I've been trying to find herding classes in Japan but I can't find any. Concretely, the problem is the Sheepdog Society Japan has this blog:

http://blog.goo.ne.jp/jsds2014

But I looked and couldn't find any way of contacting them. The blog lists trials but I want *lessons*. I spent several hours googling for it but I just couldn't find anywhere that offers it. But they must exist since without classes they wouldn't have so many trials. So:

> Does anyone know how to either contact the sheepdog society in Japan
>   or any other way of finding lessons?

Hokkaido would be ideal as a location.

Comment: I've never been a farmer, but I'd assume most people learn sheepherding from their family.

Comment: Some listings show "Morning Mist sheep dog training center" 朝霧シープドッグトレーニングセンター  but I'm having trouble finding the location/contact details. You can comment on the post--have you tried that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about travel at all.

Comment: @mkennedy No I haven't. It would mean publishing my email address on the internet which I'm kind of reluctant to do. But maybe that's the only way.

Comment: Break it up, or get a throwaway (like a yahoo one) just for this.

Comment: @Willeke if the OP can't do sheepdog lessons at home, then it seems a legit travel question.

Comment: Do you have a dog to take with you? It's not the sort of thing generally done as a recreational activity.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm That makes everything a travel question, as long as you add 'while I am in ....' but training a dog takes more time than most people have in a holiday. So I still doubt the 'travel' connection of the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Travel, and is thus off-topic. A Japan resident seeking sheepdog training would face exactly the same challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact in Japan:

```
The Secretary
Japan Sheep Dog Society
812 Hitoana
Fujinomiya-shi
Shizuoka 4180102
JAPAN
```

Telephone: `+81(0)544 52 0258`

email: `japan_sheepdog_society [at] yahoo.co.jp`

web-site: http://blog.goo.ne.jp/jsds2014/e/a96114e3f0a64bcb5813b0d1b39f52c4